# Migrated from Solr4 to Solr6, field queries return no results

Tags: solr

I migrated my site to a completely new instance with new versions of everything (LAMP on Ubuntu). When I do a search on the old site (Solr 4) using a query such as

```
authortext:fred
```

I get lots of results. With the new site (Solr 5), I get zero results (note the data is the same). However, if I use a very specific query such as

```
authortext:Fred Smith FredSmith
```

Then I get the same results on both Solr 4 & 6. So IOWs, the Solr6 implementation only supports exact strings for field searches. Note that this particular field is defined in the schmema as "text". The schemas are (mostly) identical in both implementations - new version having more stuff in it. I'm running these queries using the Solr admin.

Here's the relevant section of schema.xml:

```
    <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1"
                    catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <!--<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>-->
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1"
                    catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
    <field name="text" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
    <field name="authortext" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

On the old Solr 4, I get errors if I surround fred with wildcards `*fred*`, but it works if I escape them `\*fred\*`. On the new Solr 6, it actually returns all the same results as the bare "fred" on the old Solr 4 site, BUT, it's still case sensitive - have to use `*Fred*`. So, it seems I could alter my php code to add wildcards to the field string that gets passed to Solr (and clip the 1st char), but that is a horrible hack. I'm presuming that there is some mystery new config that has an unpleasant default value (this phenomenon got me many times setting up the new instance)?

Debug output for Solr6:

```
"responseHeader":{
"status":0,
"QTime":0,
"params":{
  "q":"authortext:fred",
  "indent":"on",
  "wt":"json",
  "debugQuery":"on",
  "_":"1507235204701"}},
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
  },
  "debug":{
    "rawquerystring":"authortext:fred",
    "querystring":"authortext:fred",
    "parsedquery":"authortext:fred",
    "parsedquery_toString":"authortext:fred,
    "explain":{},
    "QParser":"LuceneQParser",
```

(I omitted the timing section since it's just a bunch of 0.0 sec)

Debug from Solr4:

```
[Lots of response elements omitted]
<lst name="debug">
    <str name="rawquerystring">authortext:fred</str>
    <str name="querystring">authortext:fred</str>
    <str name="parsedquery">authortext:fred</str>
    <str name="parsedquery_toString">authortext:fred</str>
<lst name="explain">
    <str name="68665">
        4.998859 = (MATCH) fieldWeight(authortext:fred in 45574), product of: 1.4142135 = tf(termFreq(authortext:fred)=2) 8.079376 = idf(docFreq=131, numDocs=110520) 0.4375 = fieldNorm(field=authortext, doc=45574)
    </str>
```

....many more "MATCHES" omitted`

Comment: What is the definition of the field `authortext`? Also, remember that `authortext:Fred Smith FredSmith` searches for `Fred` in `authortext`, but `Smith` and `FredSmith` are looked up in the _default field_ and not in `authortext`. It really doesn't seem like your definitions for the fields are the same between 4 and 6, since the definition you've pasted for `text` _should_ give a hit for just `fred`. Have you looked at what the `debugQuery` output for both versions are?

Comment: Copy/Paste error on the authortext definition. And those authortext queries should've been + delimited not space delimited. At any rate, the querydebug doesn't seem that helpful? The definitions for authortext are identical, as are the other definitions they depend on. I'm currently rebuilding the db after copying the exact same schema from 4 to 6 (takes sooo long).

Comment: `+` is only the URL format for representing spaces - If you want to have an actual space there, use "foo bar", or escape it with \.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the correct schema? What does the schema browser under the analysis page show? Have you tried reindexing, or have you copied the index files to the solr6 instance? Remember that since 4 the 'managed schema' has been introduced, so the schema.xml is only read the first time unless you've set the ClassicIndexSchemaFactory as the handler.

Comment: I'm looking at the file in /var/solr/data/my_core/conf/schema.xml. The schema browser for Solr 6 shows entries like "Fred Smith FredSmith". But for Solr 4, in the weighted list of index entries, I can find "fred", "smith", and "fredsmith". So, it seems that my Solr6 implementation is not performing the lowercase transform when generating the index?

Comment: Seems correct. Check the analysis page about how content is transformed when indexing and querying and check what the actual schema entry says.

Comment: Ok, so it just shows "Index Analyzer:
org.apache.solr.schema.FieldType$DefaultAnalyzer" for authortext - nothing in the dropdown. No filters at all. Which suggests syntax error in schema? Other fields do have filters and tokenizers defined. When I tried the Solr4 schema.xml on Solr6, nothing worked. But as far as I can tell, the relevant sections for authortext and the types are identical betw the 2? But Solr4 analysis does show filters on authortext. I guess I'll just have to keep staring at this until something hits me over the head. Sadly it takes 80min to re-index after I edit schema.xml.

Comment: Sounds like you're missing the definition for the field, yes. Usually Solr gives an exception in its logs if there's an error and refuses to load the schema, but maybe something else is off - check for startup messages. You can verify how the field behaves by going to the "analysis" page under the collection without having to reindex to see if things are behaving like you want them to.

Comment: I found an error, unused type definition, that was preventing the schema from being loaded. But, the spurious type was in the solrconfig.xml file. Deleting that uncovered another error in a dynamic type, but then, at long last, the schema loaded and the authortext was fully defined with filters/tokenizers and now it all works again. Thanks for the help and suggestions.

Comment: Good to hear, np!